# match string with comma javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match

I want to match string with or without comma and space:

```
<div>
"hello world"
<br>
"hello,world"
<br>
"hello world,"
<br>
",hello world"
<br>
",hello,world,"
<br>
", hello , world ,"
</div>
```

so if i search for example "world" i want to find it with or without comma and space and highlight the result

```
 var search = "world";
 //or
 var search = "world,";
 //or
 var search = ",world";
 //or
 var search = ",world,";
 div.replace(new RegExp('(' + search + ')', 'gi'), '<span class="highlighted">$1</span>')
```

like this:

```
<div>
    "hello <span class="highlighted">world</span>"
    <br>
    "hello<span class="highlighted">,world</span>"
    <br>
    "hello <span class="highlighted">world,</span>"
    <br>
    ",hello <span class="highlighted">world</span>"
    <br>
    ",hello<span class="highlighted">,world,</span>"
    <br>
    ", hello <span class="highlighted">, world ,</span>"
```

here an example of what i want :
https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/5/

i solved it thanks to TMKelleher
https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/6/

Comment: Also try this regex `(?:,\s*)?world(?:\s*,)?` [check demo](https://regex101.com/r/tO7gB5/1).

Comment: thanks this works for one world what about if i search for "hello world" how to to match "hello,world" and ", hello , world ,"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
/([\s,]\s*world\s*,?)/i
```

`[\s,]` let's us either have a space or a comma to ensure there is a separation between the words. Then following it with `\s*` allows for zero to many white spaces between the comma/space and the word `world`. We then follow that up with some more `\s*` before the `,?` which means one or none commas. Then we capture `()` it with a case insensitive, `i`, regular expression.

---

This should handle the replacing.

```html
<style>
.highlighted {
   background-color: rgb(100,100,255);
   color: white;
}
</style>

<div id = "0">
"hello world"
<br>
"hello,world"
<br>
"hello world,"
<br>
",hello world"
<br>
",hello,world,"
<br>
", hello , world ,"
</div>
<div id="1"></div>

<script>
var content = document.getElementById("0").innerHTML.split("<br>"),
    result  = [];
for(var i in content) {
    // First extract what we want.
    var world = /([\s,]\s*world\s*,?)/.exec(content[i])[1],
    // Split everything up to make the insertion easier.
    hello     = content[i].split(world);
    // Place the result back.
    result.push(hello.join('<span class="highlighted">'+world+'</span>'));
}
document.getElementById("1").innerHTML = result.join("<br>");
</script>
```

---

**UPDATE** To fit what @jsem asked down in the comments, I created a function that will determine the correct phrase, such as "hello world" or the many others based off of the search and punctuation.

```
function separate(search, punc) {
   if(typeof punc !== "string") punc = ",";
   var phrase = new RegExp(".*?(\\w+)\\s*(?:"+punc+"|\\s)\\s*(\\w+)\\s*(?:"+punc+")?","i").exec(search);
   if(!phrase) throw new Error("Search passed could not be parsed.");
   return {word1:phrase[1], word2:phrase[2]};
};
```

Then used the information gathered from that to create a unique regular expression that will grab the information to be highlighted.

```
function build_regex(phrase, punc) {
    if(typeof punc !== "string") punc = ",";
    return new RegExp("^.*?"+phrase.word1+"\\s*((?:"+punc+"|\\s)\\s*"+phrase.word2+"\\s*(?:"+punc+")?).*$", "i");
};
```

With these two functions, I created a highlighting function using the same splitting and joining algorithm as before.

```
function highlight(sentence, search, punc) {
    if(typeof punc !== "string") punc = ",";
    var highlighted = build_regex(separate(search, punc), punc).exec(sentence)[1],
        remains     = sentence.split(highlighted);
    return remains.join('<span class="highlighted">'+highlighted+'</span>');
};
```

**Ex:**

```
highlight("This is my sentence hello, world!", "hello world");
/* Output: This is my sentence hello<span class="highlighted">, world</span>!*/
highlight("Change things up... sir.", "up sir", "\\.\\.\\.");
/* Output: Change things up<span class="highlighted">... sir</span>.*/
highlight("Give me some options? ummm...", "options! ummm", "\\?|\\!");
/* Output: Give me some options<span class="highlighted">? ummm</span>...*/
```

Comment: ok thank you but one more thing if i want to match "hello word"  and using the first ^ and last $ regex how to do it?

Comment: `^.*` Start from beginning grabbing everything up to what we want. `.*$` Start from ending grabbing everything. `^.*([\s,]\s*world\s*,?).*$` Not sure if that is what you meant?

Comment: i mean i want also to find when i search for "hello world" to match also "hello,world"  or " hellow, world " or" hellow ,world " or ",hellow world" or "helow world," using first and last ^ $ expression with or without space ..

Comment: Here is a a more generic of what I think you mean: `^.*?(\w+\s*[\s,]\s*\w+\s*,?).*$` The `^.*?` will grab from the beginning to the first recognized pattern non-greedy (will not grab `hello`). The `\w+` means at least one word character (for JavaScript that is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`). To see it for your "hello world" - `^.*?(hello\s*[\s,]\s*world\s*,?).*$`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: see this example of my improved text highlighter https://jsfiddle.net/nvdhqf23/5/ able to highlight Arabic and english and french diacritic when i enter for "hello world" i want to match text that have symbols or Punctuation too like "hello , world"

Comment: Does that help some?

Answer (score 1):

Try this for your regex:

```
var re = /([,|\s]+)?world([,|\s]+)?/g;
```

Comment: I got a message from the Redundance Department for Redundencies. Do you want me to read it out for you? ;-) (hint: `/[, \s]*world[, \s]*/` should suffice)

Comment: @deamentiaemundi I got more message from the department (hint: `[, \s]`==`[,\s]`) :D

Comment: @bobblebubble yes, the space was redundant, The RDofR didn't get its name for nothing! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `?` optional sign right after the commas in your `search` variable:

```
var search = ",?world,?";
```

And, if you really want to match spaces (to hilight?!), just add `\s*`, which means from zero to many spaces:

```
div.replace(new RegExp('(\\s*' + search + '\\s*)', 'gi'), ...
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The last example with `RegExp('(\s*' + search + '\s*)', 'gi')` won't help because of backslashes.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated